# way to show image from asset and store it in SD card

Tags: android, webview, imageview

I am creating one wallpaper application therefore i put some image in asset folder. I need to show this image one by one on button click and store it in sd card.
**What i did**: 
I use ImageView and WebView to show image. First, when i use WebView, i stuck on setting image size because it showing to small and i need to show those image as per device window size.
I use following code but didn't help to adjust image on screen

```
myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/image.html");
    WebSettings settings = myWebView.getSettings();
    settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
```

I also set `<src img="someimage.jpg" width=""100%">` but it didn't help me.

Then i use ImageView to show image and able to show image at least in some proper size using following code.

```
InputStream ims = getAssets().open("31072011234.jpg");
        // load image as Drawable
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(ims, null);
        // set image to ImageView
        imageView.setImageDrawable(d);
```

**My Question is**
Which is the good way to show image on screen imageview or webview?. how to take all picture in array when i don't know name of this images and store it in SD card
Give me some hint or reference.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you loading image from assets? Why not resources?

Comment: Ok.. whether it from asset or resources but which is the best way to show?

Comment: As webView is a heavy component i will prefer you to use simple imageView.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to show an image would be `ImageView` (That's why it's called an **Image** View), I recommend that you add the image in `res/drawable` folder and show the image using:

```
imageView.setImageResource(R.id.some_image);
```

The resource can be saved to sdcard using:

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource( getResources(), R.id.some_image);
String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
File file = new File(extStorageDirectory, "someimage.PNG");
outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
outStream.flush();
outStream.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put your images in `assets` folder, you can use `res/drawable` to store your images and access it as `resource`.

Using below code you can access images from drawable without need to know the names of image files.

```
Class resources = R.drawable.class;
    Field[] fields = resources.getFields();
    String[] imageName = new String[fields.length];     
    int index = 0;
    for( Field field : fields )
    {
        imageName[index] = field.getName();
        index++;
    }

    int result = getResources().getIdentifier(imageName[10], "drawable", "com.example.name");
```

and using below code you can save your images to SD card.

```
File file = new File(extStorageDirectory, "filename.PNG");
 outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
 bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
 outStream.flush();
 outStream.close();
```

Comment: can getField() get all images from drawable? if i have some .xml file along with images then it will show only images or also show .xml file?